# prolog - tail recursion issue

Tags: list, recursion, prolog, tail-recursion

I am new to prolog and I am trying to create a predicate and am having some trouble.

I have a list of cities that are connected via train. They are connected via my links/2 clause.

```
links(toronto, ajax).
links(toronto, markham).
links(toronto, brampton).
links(brampton, markham).
links(markham, ajax).
links(brampton, mississauga).
links(mississauga, toronto).
links(mississuaga, oakville).
links(oakville, st.catharines).
links(oakville, hamilton).
links(hamilton, st.catharines).
```

I am writing a predicate called addnewcities which will take a list of cities and then return a new list containing the original list, plus all the cities that are directly connected to each of the cities in the original list.

Here is a (rough looking) visual representation of the links.
[image]

If my input list was `[toronto]` I want my output to be (order doesnt matter) `[ajax,markham,brampton,mississauga,toronto]`.

If input was `[oakville,hamilton]` I want the output to be `[mississauga,st.catharines,oakville,hamilton]`.

Here is my predicate so far.

```
addnewcities([],_).
addnewcities([CitiesH|Tail],Ans):- directer(CitiesH,Ans2),  merger(Ans2,[CitiesH],Ans), addnewcities(Tail,Ans).
```

`directer/2` takes a city and saves a list containing all the directly connected cities in the second arg.

`merger/3` just merges two lists making sure there are no duplicates in the final list.

When my input is a list with one element ie `[toronto]` it works!
But when I have a list with multiple elements `[toronto,ajax]` it says "false" every time.

I'm pretty sure my issue is that when it recurses for the second time, merge is what says its false. I just don't know how to get around this so that my list can keep being updated instead of being checked if true or false.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `merge/3` will fail on the recursive call `addcities(Tail,Ans)` because on that recursive call you have instantiated `Ans`. The call to `merge(Ans2,[CitiesH],Ans)` attempts to merge `Ans2` with `[CitiesH]` and can't match the result that is already instantiated in `Ans`, so it fails. The recursive call `addcities(Tail,Ans)` needs to an unbound variable for the second argument. Then you'll need to figure out what to do with that unbound variable.

Comment: I see now why and where it is failing. But I just can't figure out how to fix it. Should I be creating a different predicate and then send that unbound variable to is and do the work there?

Comment: Just think carefully through what your recursive clause means logically. `addcities([CitiesH|Tail],Ans) :-` means *`Ans` is a list of all the cities directly connected to cities in the list `[CitiesH|Tail]` if...* and express the rest of it in words you can translate to Prolog.

Answer (score 1):

this query uses library support to solve the problem:

```
addcities(Cs, L) :-
  setof(D, C^(member(C,Cs), (C=D;link(C,D);link(D,C))), L).
```

Comment: This produces the exact result I need! Is there anyway you can explain to me what the caret does? I have been looking for documentation about it but can't find anything. Thanks!

Comment: Short explanation: the caret tells Prolog to **not** bind the variable. To get a clue about what this means: findall/3 doesn't bind any variable. See the SWI-Prolog documentation for [bagof](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=bagof/3)/3

Answer (score 1):

This should work for what you want:

```
addcities(A,B):-
    addcitiesaux(A,[],B).

addcitiesaux([],X,X).

addcitiesaux([X|Xs],L,R):-
    link(X,A),
    \+ member(A,L),
    !,
    addcitiesaux([X|Xs],[A|L],R).

addcitiesaux([X|Xs],L,R):-
    link(A,X),
    \+ member(A,L),
    !,
    addcitiesaux([X|Xs],[A|L],R).

 addcitiesaux([X|Xs],L,R):-
    addcitiesaux(Xs,[X|L],R).
```

Comment: This answer is close, but the resulting list doesn't include the cities in the original list all the time.

Comment: Sorry, I didn´t read that you should include the cities from the original list, you can add them by including X in the last predicate. You can see the answer edited.